# Using javascript to get a unix timestamp of a future event to save in database

Tags: javascript, unix, firebase

I'm currently building a fantasy sports website where i need to save future events in my firebase database where i will have to account for that locations timezone.

My thinking was along the lines of calculating a unix timestamp using the date and time of the event & timezone then saving that into the database for future reference to count down to it etc.

I can't quite figure out how to make this work, i believe moment.js is the right move here but it has me confused if this is maybe the best option or not.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Ryann,

Comment: This may have come across wrong, i basically do not know how to get the unix timestamp of a future datetime in a specific timezone

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved it using Moment Timezone

```
let timezone:string = this.round.timezone;                // America/Los_Angeles
let date:string = this.round.eventDate                    // 2017-01-07
let gateOpenTime = this.round.gateOpenTime;               // 12:00
let momentStringGate:string = date + ' ' + gateOpenTime;  // 2017-01-07 12:00
this.round.gateOpenUnix = moment.tz(momentStringGate, timezone).unix();  //1483819200
```